# how to override javascript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, lookup

I am trying to override item and add new item/object in given array of objects .

here is my code

```
const replaceOrAdd = (sourceArray, overrideArray, key = "name") => {
  const existingIndex = sourceArray.findIndex(
    (item) => item[key] === overrideArray[key]
  );

  if (existingIndex >= 0) {
    sourceArray[existingIndex] = overrideArray;
  } else {
    sourceArray.push(overrideArray);
  }

  return sourceArray;
};

const source = [
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE",
    name: "validity_date",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_TYPE",
    name: "booking_type",
    rules: {},
    visible: true,
  },
];

const replace = [
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "XXXXX",
    name: "XXXXXX",
    visible: false,
  },
];

replaceOrAdd(source, replace);

console.log(source);
```

**Expected output** :

```
 [
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE",
    name: "validity_date",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_TYPE",
    name: "booking_type",
    rules: {},
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "XXXXX",
    name: "XXXXXX",
    visible: false,
  },
];
```

I am trying to override in the source array if "name" key match .. if they there is extra object in replace object . I am trying to add that object.

Here in example  **name: "job_order_number",** , **name: "booking_number",** match .. I want to override this object and add this object **name: "XXXXXX",** as it is not found

Comment: loop through the override array and do find and replace https://codeshare.io/r9N1JY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you will like to mutate the original array. You can use the `replaceOrAdd` to return a new array & inside this function you can create a `map` from the `sourceArray` then iterate over the `overrideArray` and add its value to the `map`. If the `map` has the `key` then it will override else it will add the value.

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (sourceArray, overrideArray, key = "name") => {
  const sourceMap = new Map();
  sourceArray.forEach((item) => {
    sourceMap.set(item[key], item)
  });

  overrideArray.forEach(item => {
    sourceMap.set(item[key], item)
  });
  return Array.from(sourceMap, ([name, value]) => value);
};

const source = [{
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE",
    name: "validity_date",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_TYPE",
    name: "booking_type",
    rules: {},
    visible: true,
  },
];

const replace = [{
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "XXXXX",
    name: "XXXXXX",
    visible: false,
  },
];
console.log(replaceOrAdd(source, replace));
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach which does everything within a single full iteration-cycle could be based on [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where one builds/aggregates both the lookup-object and the result-array while iterating a [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enated version of both passed arrays. One could even further prevent the mutatation of original data references by [structurally cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) each item which gets added to the result-array.

This approach comes with the cost of a single concatenation and a single, `reduce` based, iteration. No other iterations needed, like `forEach` or `Array.from`. A direct, object based, lookup does not add to the costs, unlike array based alternatives like `includes`, `find` or `findIndex`.

```js
function overrideOrAdd(sourceArray, overrideArray, key = "label") {
  return sourceArray

    .concat(overrideArray)
    .reduce(({ lookup, result }, item) => {

      const groupName = item[key];
      const lookupItem = lookup[groupName];

      if (!lookupItem) {

        // ....either add/collect a new copy of the item ...
        result.push(
          lookup[groupName] = structuredClone(item)
        );
      } else {
        // ... or override/mutate the before added/copied one.
        Object.assign(lookupItem, item);
      }
      return { lookup, result };

    }, { lookup: {}, result: [] }).result;
};
const result = overrideOrAdd(source, override);

console.log({ result, source, override });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const source = [{
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: true,
  }, {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE",
    name: "validity_date",
    visible: true,
  }, {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: true,
  }, {
    label: "BOOKING_TYPE",
    name: "booking_type",
    rules: {},
    visible: true,
  }];

  const override = [{
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: false,
  }, {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: false,
  }, {
    label: "XXXXX",
    name: "XXXXXX",
    visible: false,
  }];
</script>
```

Comment: A nice approach.  I don't think the full power of `structuredClone` is necessary here, since when you combine, you do so with `Object.assign`.  Instead, I believe you could just do `lookup[groupName] = {...item}`.  My answer also stores the values in objects, but uses different ones for source and overrides, and then extracts and combines the keys from each.  I'm guessing yours is somewhat more efficient.  I like my shorter code, but it involves depending upon the iteration order of objects -- even though it's now well-specified and universally implemented, I still don't like doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Here we turn the source and override arrays into objects keyed off your key property, with values just being the original objects.

Then we take the unique set of keys from these objects and `map` over the keys combining them into new Objects with a naive merge:

```js
k => ({...x[k], ...y[k]})
```

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (s, o, key = "name",
  [x, y] = [s, o].map((xs) => Object.fromEntries(xs.map((x) => [x[key], x])))
) => [...new Set([...Object.keys(x), ...Object.keys(y)])].map(k => ({...x[k], ...y[k]}))

const source = [{label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER", name: "job_order_number", visible: !0}, {label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE", name: "validity_date", visible: !0}, {label: "BOOKING_ID", name: "booking_number", visible: !0}, {label: "BOOKING_TYPE", name: "booking_type", rules: {}, visible: !0}]
const override = [{label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER", name: "job_order_number", visible: !1}, {label: "BOOKING_ID", name: "booking_number", visible: !1}, {label: "XXXXX", name: "XXXXXX", visible: !1}]

console.log(replaceOrAdd(source, override))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that this does not mutate your original arrays.  We're not barbarians here, right?

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to mutate the original array, so iterate the replace array and find existing item with the same property value. If found, replace the item, otherwise push it:

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (sourceArray, overrideArray, key = "name") => 
  overrideArray.forEach(item => {
    const found = sourceArray.findIndex(({[key]:id}) => item[key] === id);
    found >= 0 ? sourceArray[found] = item : sourceArray.push(item);
  });

const source = [
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_VALIDITY_DATE",
    name: "validity_date",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: true,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_TYPE",
    name: "booking_type",
    rules: {},
    visible: true,
  },
];

const replace = [
  {
    label: "WORK_ORDER_NUMBER",
    name: "job_order_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "BOOKING_ID",
    name: "booking_number",
    visible: false,
  },
  {
    label: "XXXXX",
    name: "XXXXXX",
    visible: false,
  },
];

replaceOrAdd(source, replace);

console.log(source);
```